# Precise definition of a Riemann surface associated to a function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}$
Let $\Omega \subset \C$ be an open and $f: \Omega \to \C$ be a meromorphic function.  I want a precise definition of THE Riemann surface associated to $f$(and some uniqueness statement).

---

Cause for my confusion:  In every book that I can find, I have seen examples of Riemann surfaces associated to a function but no precise definition.

Here is my first stab at a definition.

> A Riemann surface for $f$ is a pair $(X,F)$, where $X$ is a Riemann surface, $F: X \to \C$ is meromorphic and $F|_U=f$ for some chart and coordinates $U \subset X$.

Obviously the Riemann surface for $f$ is not unique in any sense right now.

The uniqueness statement that I want is something like

> Given $(X,F)$, $(Y,G)$ as above, then there is an isomorphism $X \cong Y$ such that the following diagram commutes

$\require{AMScd}$

$\begin{CD}
X @>F>> \C\\
@| @|\\
Y @>G>> \C
\end{CD}
$

Is this too much to ask?  And is there a definition of the Riemann surface associated to a function so that I can get such a uniqueness statement?

Comment: This may help : http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~pablo/download/teichmuller/node14.html

Comment: Thanks.  Are you telling me that I can only aim to get a uniqueness statement if I restrict to marked Riemann surfaces, under Riemann equivalence?